# Additive Color in Highcharts

Tags: svg, highcharts, colors

I am plotting overlapping polygons with differnt colors in Highchart in the following example.

http://jsfiddle.net/525hx0oq/25/

Also radiant color has no effect on mixing of color

```
  color:  {
                 radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.5, r: 0.5 },
                 stops: [
                 [0, '#003399'],
                 [1, '#3366AA']
                 ]
            },
```

But i see there is no mixing of color when the two different color overlaps each other like what i am supposed to get as follows.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_color#/media/File:AdditiveColor.svg

Can u pls help me how can i achieve this using Highcarts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a transparent color, instead of solid. To do this you need to use `'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'` with alpha channel (last param).

Example:
- http://jsfiddle.net/525hx0oq/85/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by "**like what i am supposed to get**"?

There should not be any "mixing of color" in your scenario - you are just drawing one colored area on top of another, and whatever is in front is what is visible. They are not interacting in any deeper way.

The file that you linked to is just an illustration of additive color - not an example of what happens when you overlap colors in SVG.

You need to either use transparent colors as Sebastian suggested, which (by definition) will not be fully saturated, or you need to calculate the area and color of the overlap and plot it that way yourself.

Think if it as cutting polygons out of construction paper and stacking them on top of each other on the table - you can either use translucent paper that will let the colors show through, or you can cut out more shapes in more colors to fit into the overlapping spots.